# Secondary data type

Tags: java, class, interface

Consider the following statement:
"A superclass provides a secondary data type to objects of its subclass"

Similarly,
"An interface provides a secondary data type to objects of classes that implement that interface."

What is a secondary data type and what does it mean in these statements? An example would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a statement to be clarified you need to provide the context (source).

Comment: Polimorphism https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: Foo extends Bar, then you can reference Foo by Foo as well as Bar, hence providing secondary data type

Comment: They are from a Java textbook. The quotes are from a table comparing and contracting interfaces & classes. Sorry, if I was unclear.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, are you saying your answer to this question would depend on which Java text book the statements come from?

Comment: I think it's best understood by an example. A secondary data type to a `LinkedList` would be `Queue` for instance. I think the wording is unfortunate though. I would say, *"A superclass provides an alternative view of the objects of its subclasses"*.

Comment: @aioobe Not necessarily, but it would at least be nice for other visitors to understand the context. It adds to the usefulness of the question and answers. Besides that, quoting your sources is the right thing to do, if only for us to be able to check the correctness.

Answer (score 1):

It means that a sub-class instance can be assigned to a variable of the super-class, and similarly an instance of a class that implements an interface can be assigned to a variable of the interface type.

```
public class BaseClass {}
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {}

public interface Inter {}
public class InterImpl implements Inter {}

...

BaseClass var1 = new SubClass ();
Inter var2 = new InterImpl ();
```

And an example with real classes/interfaces :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // ArrayList is a class that implements List
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>(); // LinkedHashMap is a sub-class of HashMap
```

Comment: @user5514883 You can say that `ArrayList` has a secondary type - the `List` interface. Similarly you can say that `LinkedHashMap` has a secondary type - its super class `HashMap`. Actually there can be more than one secondary type. For `ArrayList`, `Collection` is also a secondary type (since it's a super-interface of `List`, and the `Object` class is a secondary type for all classes, since all classes are sub-classes of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow scenario like,

```
class SuperA{...}
class SubA extends SuperA{...}

interface SuperAInterface{...}
class ImplementsofSuperAInterface implemets ASuperAInterface{...}
```

so that you can do something like this,

```
SuperA refA = new SubA();
ImplementsofSuperAInterface  refA = new ASuperAInterface();
```

**Ultimately, you can use Parent/Super-Class/Interface's reference variable which point's it's derived class' instance.**